# Header file issue: Multiple definition error; first defined here

Tags: c

I am having trouble with multiple definitions of functions. All other solutions here on stack overflow have not worked out for me.

This is my main.c:

```
#include "lib.h"
int main(){
   test();
}
```

This is the lib.c file:

```
#include "lib.h"
int var;
void test(){
//code here
}
```

And this is the lib.h file:

```
#ifndef _HTTPLIB_H_
#define _HTTPLIB_H_
#include <stdio.h>

extern int var;

extern void test();

#endif
```

I have checked and there are no definitions of any function twice and I am never including a .c source file.

I am compiling with

```
gcc lib.c main.c -Wall -g -o main

main: In function 'test': (.text+0xfdd): multiple definition of 'test'    /tmp/ccb8byZi.o:lib.c:(.text+0xef9): first defined here'
```

real code:
    main file: http://pastebin.com/xr3DF0TE
    lib.c and lib.h file: http://pastebin.com/KemhKX3f

This is the compilation code

```
gcc -lpthread -D_REENTRANT httplib.c http.c -o -g http
```

real error message:

```
http: In function `sigusr1':(.text+0xfdd): multiple definition of `sigusr1'/tmp/ccb8byZi.o:httplib.c:(.text+0xef9): first defined here
```

Comment: #include "lib.h" not lib.c

Comment: that was a typo, im not including lib.c but lib.h

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: `_HTTPLIB_H_` is technically a reserved identifier (anything starting with `_` and an uppercase letter or another `_` is).

Comment: i am compiling with gcc lib.c main.c -Wall -g -o main

Comment: main: In function 'test':
(.text+0xfdd): multiple definition of 'test'
/tmp/ccb8byZi.o:lib.c:(.text+0xef9): first defined here'

Comment: That error says you have a `test` function in `main`. This does not match the code you posted here. Show your real code.

Comment: With the exact files you give I get no errors at all, on two different platforms.  So my guess is that you are not actually doing what you think you are.

Comment: Do you have function prototype in lib.c, because looking at error it seems you have.

Comment: All I get is `main.c:4:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]` because my gcc doesn't default to C99 rules yet. No linker errors. Voting to close because no [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @melpomene ubuntu? please! update it :p

Comment: I dont have a prototype in my lib.c file

Comment: Your real code doesn't contain a `test` function so I have no idea how you got that error.

Comment: I was creating a example with test. I actually get that in all the functions in the real code

Comment: So what's the *actual error message you get* not some made up version of it?

Comment: I tried with your "real" code and now I get `httplib.h:6:20: fatal error: semlib.h: No such file or directory` (also, I had to rename `lib.h` to `httplib.h` to get this far).

Comment: That's not the real error message. Or at least that's not how it's actually formatted. And you're (again) missing the command that produced the error message.

Comment: yea that is a custom semaphore lib that was provided to me, actually ended up not using it so you can remove it

Comment: After removing that include: `lib.c:299: undefined reference to \`pthread_join'`

Comment: try with the command i have provided up there maybe

Comment: FINALLY! You provided the actual compilation command I asked you for 40 minutes ago!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gcc -lpthread -D_REENTRANT httplib.c http.c -o -g http
```

Here's your problem: You're telling gcc to compile 3 files (`httplib.c`, `http.c`, `http`) into an executable called `-g`. This is because the argument after `-o` is taken to be the output filename.

The errors are caused by you apparently having an `http` executable lying around, which already contains the (compiled) functions defined in `httplib.c`.

Fix:

```
gcc -lpthread -D_REENTRANT httplib.c http.c -g -o http
```